# Reece Calendar event

Tags: php

I have this problem with the script:

Notice: Undefined index: show_times in C:\wamp\www\ReeceCalendar_0.9\cal\gatekeeper.php  on line 192

Notice: Undefined index: hours_24 in C:\wamp\www\ReeceCalendar_0.9\cal\gatekeeper.php on line 194

Notice: Undefined index: start_monday in C:\wamp\www\ReeceCalendar_0.9\cal\gatekeeper.php on line 196

Notice: Undefined index: anon_naming in C:\wamp\www\ReeceCalendar_0.9\cal\gatekeeper.php on line 198

and the codes for each line are:

192:  if($d['show_times']=='y')  $cal_options['show_times'] = TRUE;

194:  if($d['hours_24']=='y')  $cal_options['hours_24'] = TRUE;

196:  if($d['start_monday']=='y') $cal_options['start_monday'] = TRUE;

198:  if($d['anon_naming']=='y')  $cal_options['anon_naming'] = TRUE;

Please help me!Thnx

Answer (score 1):

It seems that this code was written with notices turned off. If you don't want to rewrite the code you can decrease errors level. Put following line on beginning of script:

```
error_reporting (E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE);
```

or change php.ini:

error_reporting = E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE but this is not recommended as it will turn off notices for all your scripts.

You can read about PHP errors reporting levels [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.constants.php).

Comment: It doesn't work,I have to modify that line not change the php.ini:(

Comment: Ok, so you have to check does array key exists before checking its value, like:
if(isset ($d['show_times']) && $d['show_times']=='y') $cal_options['show_times'] = TRUE;

or you can use array_key_exists function, like: if (array_key_exists ('show_times', $d) && $d['show_times']=='y') $cal_options['show_times'] = TRUE;